# How to add PropertyGroup-s or ItemGroup-s into a csproj via nuget

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, csproj

For my nuget package to work correctly, there must be certain sections present in the `csproj` file. If I add these sections manually, either through manipulating the target project or adding a `.targets` file, it works correctly.

I want to do the same, but automatically, so that just by referencing my nuget package,my custom `PropertyGroup`s get injected into the C# project.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to add `.props` or `.targets` file with specified sections and then put them into `build` directory of package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

Comment: putting the props and targets in `build/<tfm>/` is better, otherwise NuGet will think the package is compatible with all TFMs, including C++ projects, UWP, etc. Unless your package extends the build (like git versioning, source link), don't use the `build/` folder directly.